# Php substr entire words

Tags: php

How can i substr 20 chars from $xbio and get only complete words?

```
$xbio = 'word1 ord2 word3 word4 and so on';
echo ''.substr($xbio, 0, 20).'...';
```

TY

Found this searching stackoverflow - tell me what do you think please:

```
<? $xbio = preg_replace('/\s+?(\S+)?$/', '', substr($xbio, 0, 50)); ?>
```

Comment: Take a look at http://php.net/manual/en/function.wordwrap.php

Comment: you have to define a term "word" first. PHP do not know what do you mean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
preg_match('/^([a-zA-Z0-9 ]{1,20})\\b/', $xbio, $matches);
echo $matches[1];
```

Comment: I made it 20, sorry.. had it 30 for testing. This matches up to 20 characters, but makes it must end in a space or the end of the line.

Comment: ry matching on \b instead of "( |$)" instead.  \b matches word boundaries and will cover other breaks like newlines, tabs etc. that your current approach misses.  See http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.escape.php for details.

Answer (score 1):

This is the function i always use:

```
# advanced substr
function gen_string($string,$min) {
    $text = trim(strip_tags($string));
    if(strlen($text)>$min) {
        $blank = strpos($text,' ');
        if($blank) {
            # limit plus last word
            $extra = strpos(substr($text,$min),' ');
            $max = $min+$extra;
            $r = substr($text,0,$max);
            if(strlen($text)>=$max) $r=trim($r,'.').'...';
        } else {
            # if there are no spaces
            $r = substr($text,0,$min).'...';
        }
    } else {
        # if original length is lower than limit
        $r = $text;
    }
    return $r;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a function that i use for this kind of task:

```
function truncate($str, $maxLength, $append = '...') {
    if (strlen($str) > $maxLength) {
        $str = substr($str, 0, $maxLength);
        $str = preg_replace('/\s+.*?$/', '', $str); // this line is important for you
        $str = trim($str);
        $str .= $append:
    }

    return $str;
}
```

Comment: I think your `preg_replace` misses some arguments. :)